# Training A Restricted Boltzmann Machine with gray-scale images

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I am trying to train a feed forward neural net for image classification. In this process, I am implementing a restricted boltzmann machine to help pre-train the weights.

My images are grey-scale with pixel intensities from 0-255.

I was wondering how to sample and turn these pixels into binary since their intensities do not offer a representation of their probabilities. I also normalized these features to zero mean and unit variance.